# clion LLDB & Qt formatter scripts

Tags: clion

Clion just got lldb support on win msvc (yay!) and I do wonder... how can I install formatter script to it?

I found out this info/repo

`https://unlimitedcodeworks.xyz/blog/2016/08/20/gsoc-kdevelop-lldb-final-report/#using-data-formatter-scripts-outside-kdevelop`

and

`https://cgit.kde.org/kdevelop.git/tree/plugins/lldb/formatters?id=a4e6c0aa1597e1c9558139da7a5e76fdadd075a8`

But not sure what/where to put it... ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `~/.lldbinit` file.

Use [`command script import <python formatter file path>`](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/lldb%20formatters) in your `~/.lldbinit`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for info! Where do I put the lldbinit? In C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 192.4787.12\bin\lldb I have helpers/renderers and win... not sure here...

Comment: In your home directory, I think, in `c:\Users\name\`. Check out what lldb docs says about Windows.

Comment: Thanks! will this allso apply to lldb that come with clion?